# How "linux process address space" is stored?

Tags: linux, process, malloc, virtual-memory

Read from the book that when a process is started, its private process address space is created

Let's say it is from 0x0 to 0xMAX

And one part of the space is the heap, and we wrote a for loop to coontinue malloc (1k date) until it returns false. It allocated 3GB date.

So, question, if 0x0 to 0xMAX is allocated in the beginning, it means 0x0 to 0xMAX is larger than 3GB (since there are stack, control...) since the beginning?

If one process can take more than 3GB at the beginning, it must be I understand it wrong.

Can anyone explain how this 0x0 - 0xMAX is stored in the begging?

Comment: no. running a process doesn't magically allocate the entire possible memory space for the app. the compiler can calculate how much memory is required to store the code and static data, and that memory will be allocated that at process startup.

Comment: @MarcB Like my process, it can take in argument to create either 3GB or 3MB heap which the compile can hardly know. So, in that case, will the operating system dynamically update the entire memory space? as heap is from 0xXX continue to 0xMax, and stack is from 0xMax till downward. it OS want to update it dynamically, the entire space will be update.

Comment: @marcb , Probably a bit tangential but there is some copy-on-write from the parent process when a fork occurs.

Comment: @MattJoyce I tried to use linux kernel api to print the map, I can see Code/Data address was not changed. And the start and 0xMAX was not changed when the heap goes up till 3GB. So I believe the address for this address space is not real hard disk / swap / or even memory address.

Comment: I recommend if you've got the time and money a copy of 'The Linux Programming Interface':  http://man7.org/tlpi/  It's the linux equivalent of Stevens Advanced Unix Programming.

Comment: http://man7.org/tlpi/download/TLPI-24-Process_Creation.pdf <--- This is a pretty good intro to linux process creation.

Comment: I think you need to go learn about virtual vs physical memory. All processes have access to their own entire virtual memory space (roughly). The kernel manages mapping virtual memory to physical memory. The program does not (in general) see the physical addresses at all. So the kernel is free to manage the physical memory so that all processes have access to the required physical memory when needed. This is a big topic and not something easily answer in Stackoverflow format.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Normally the loading of an executable to the memory is process driven by the linux loader ld. For example, if I create a very simple C program lets say:

```
void main {}
```

After compiling this program with gcc, we get an executable file (ELF format) a.out. If we analyze the dependencies this very simple program have by running ldd we find:

```
linux-gate.so.1 =>  (0x00545000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00ccb000)
/lib/ld-linux.so.2 (0x00594000)
```

The first one linux-gate.so is exposed by the kernel to make system calls. ld-linux.so is actually the linux loader. It's the reponsible of loading any executable in the memory and run it. If we take a look to our generated a.out (by using hexedit tool e.g) we can see that it's header contains a reference to where the ld-linux is located:

```
 .ELF........................4...8.......
 4. ...(.........4...4...4... ... .......
 ........T...T...T.......................
 ........................................
 ........................(...(...(.......
 ................h...h...h...D...D.......
 ....P.td............4...4...........Q.td
 ............................R.td........
 ..................../lib/ld-linux.so.2..
 ............GNU.........................
 ....GNU....F*QLk$,.....)..Yl............
```

Once you start the process, the ld-linux loader first checks what shared libraries you need (depend on) and if they are available or not. In case you depend on some shared library that's not available ld-linux won't load the process (ld-linux looks in your LD_LIBRARY_PATH env variable, /etc/ld.so.cache file and finally in the default paths: /lib and /usr/lib (man ld-linux for more information).

Once the ld-linux assures that all the libraries are there, it allocates the memory to load the process. Normally an executable has several segments, for simplicity we can reduce them to text (code), bss (uninitialized data), data (initialized and static data). When the process is loaded into memory the loader reserve the memory amount needed to hold all these sections, and map into the virtual space of the process all the shared libraries that the process depends on. You can see the list of the maps of a certain process in linux by consulting:

```
cat /proc/pid_of_process/maps
```

If I run a modified version of the simple program above (by adding a call to a usleep in order to get the process pid) and check its maps, We get the following (the _ are just to hide the real path where my home appears):

```
003a5000-003a6000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0          [vdso]
0075a000-008fd000 r-xp 00000000 08:03 2137894    /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc-2.15.so
008fd000-008ff000 r--p 001a3000 08:03 2137894    /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc-2.15.so
008ff000-00900000 rw-p 001a5000 08:03 2137894    /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc-2.15.so
00900000-00903000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
00e4a000-00e6a000 r-xp 00000000 08:03 2137906    /lib/i386-linux-gnu/ld-2.15.so
00e6a000-00e6b000 r--p 0001f000 08:03 2137906    /lib/i386-linux-gnu/ld-2.15.so
00e6b000-00e6c000 rw-p 00020000 08:03 2137906    /lib/i386-linux-gnu/ld-2.15.so
08048000-08049000 r-xp 00000000 08:05 3589145    /______________/test/a.out
08049000-0804a000 r--p 00000000 08:05 3589145    /______________/test/a.out
0804a000-0804b000 rw-p 00001000 08:05 3589145    /______________/test/a.out
b771f000-b7720000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
b7745000-b7747000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
bf884000-bf8a5000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0          [stack]
```

This is actually the **virtual** memory map of the process. These pages are mapped to physical memory and each process has its own PMT (program map table) which is used to translate between virtual and physical addresses. In general, a process memory has the following layout:

(from http://duartes.org/gustavo/blog/post/anatomy-of-a-program-in-memory/)

[image]

So, with this information in mind and going back to your original question,

> So, question, if 0x0 to 0xMAX is allocated in the beginning, it means 0x0 to 0xMAX is larger than 3GB (since there are stack, control...) since the beginning?

The answer is there's no such reservation. The loader reserve the needed **physical** memory to run the process. After that, depending on the process needs (dynamic memory allocation) and its behavior, its heap and stack areas could grow and shrink. Each time the process needs to access some memory (virtual) that's not actually present in the physical memory, a page-fault is issued and this page is load from the disk to the reserved location in the physical memory. Some times in order to do this the kernel has to swap out some page that belongs to another process to the disk. Physical memory is a limited resource which the OS has to handle correctly in order to afford all the running processes.

With this strategy the linux kernel is able to run several processes where each one normally has a virtual memory of 4GB (32 bits systems) in a physical memory minor than that (specially in the past). In general even if you reserve memory dynamically (by using malloc e.g) the call succeeds but in fact you are not reserving this physical memory yet. Your process will get it once it tries to use it (by reading or writing to this memory).

It's maybe a long answer. I hope I didn't miss a lot of details and that it helps you to understand the anatomy of a process memory in linux.

Comment: I think the question is what if the process allocates say 100G when there is actually that much physical memory available in the system. But with the 4G  virtual memory limitation for a 32bit system.

Comment: You can't manage 100Gb of memory in a 32 bit system in a single process, you need a 64bit system for that.

Comment: ok so for a 64 bit system kernel space would be much higher range and a 100G mmaped allocation would sit below stack ?

Answer (score 0):

There are some misconceptions here. First, there is a difference between the process address dpace and the memory allocated to the process.

Second, the range of valid addresses within the address space is unlikely to be linear. It is most likely to be in several disconnected areas of memory.

If you did malloc in a loop, you were causing (a) causing valid pages to be added to the process (b) causing overhead memory to be allocated in addition to that returned by malloc.

Third, at the beginning of a process, there are page tables. (Ignoring cloning) These tables refer to nothing at the start of the process. Your process has to cause pages to be allocated and assigned to the tables.